# Slim 3. Should i use grouped routes?

Tags: php, slim

Im working on quite a big app using slim 3 as my router.
The menu structure is like this. Some routes need to be grouped and some not (i think). Im not sure how i should do this.

Example menu structure. But it will hold alot more items. Is grouping a good idea here? I mean, as you see not all "clients" has the "settings" sub page/route, but it may be will in the future. How would one write the grouping logic for this?

```
client 1
    info
    settings
    loremipsum
    loremipsum

client 2
    info
    loremipsum
    loremipsum

client 3
    info
    loremipsum
    loremipsum
```

Comment: Is "client 1" to "client X" a dynamic or a hardly coded thing?

Comment: its dynamic. by a loop.

Comment: If its dynamic, where are you getting the paths from? are they stored in a database? If this is the case then I don't think this is a question about route groups, is more a question about route pattern.

Comment: You could implement a small middleware and check the persmissions per client. Do you need an example?

Comment: @DanielO I would love one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a small middleware and check the persmissions per client.

The setting "determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware" must be set to true.

```
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

$app = new App([
    'settings' => [
        // Must be set to true to get access to route within middleware
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true
    ]
]);
```

Then add this middleware and customize it:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

// Simple Route Access Control Middleware
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) use ($container) {
    // Retrieving Current Route

    /* @var \Slim\Route $route */
    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');

    if (!$route) {
        return $next($request, $response);
    }

    $name = $route->getName();
    $groups = $route->getGroups();
    $methods = $route->getMethods();
    $arguments = $route->getArguments();

    // Do something with that information
    // Check the permissions here...
    $routePermission = $container->get(RoutePermission::class);

    if (!$routePermission->isRouteAllowed($name, $arguments['client'])) {
        // Permission denied
        return $response->withStatus(403, 'Forbidden');
    } else {
        // OK :-)
        return $next($request, $response);
    }
});
```